# How to change a char to ASCII form?

Tags: c, byte, 8051

I need change my program, how do I use some function change a char to ASCII? 
my mobile receive data from 8051, always show '0', it's not true.

char to ASCII code.

```
void Data_TX(unsigned char Y)
{
    unsigned char Buff_Y[3];

    Buff_Y[2] = (Y / 100) + 0x30;
    Buff_Y[1] = (Y / 10) % 10+0x30;
    Buff_Y[0] = (Y % 10) + 0x30;

    SBUF = *Buff_Y;
    while (TI == 0);
    TI = 0;
}
```

this's my circuit original code, LCD interfacing with 8051.

```
bit Sensor_read(unsigned char read[5]);
```

use my function.

```
Data_TX(read[2]); //read data.
Data_TX((int)read[2]); //read data, this program can't to run.
```

Comment: Very unclear, what do you mean `char` to ascii? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: char is a variable type (in C, C++ and some other languages) to store numbers. ASCII is a method to assign symbols to numbers. What do you want?

Comment: @deviantfan c++ data type? The OP: you should also decide what language it is, because the solution will depend on that.

Comment: @iharob Is "variable" type better?

Comment: No, just don't say it's a c++ type. It's a data type. It exists in c and c++ and other languages.

Comment: yes, this's C code from 8051.I need use 8051 receive data to mobile.

Comment: because, my mobile need use ASCII to receive, I need change Type.

Comment: @iharob ok, I know this's a data type, not a c/c++ type, There must be some misunderstanding, I'm sorry.

Comment: Step by step, post some more code, and describe what are you trying to do. Then remember than division in rounded so /100 will give you '3' in case of Y>249.

Comment: @TheBook What are you talking about? Integer division truncates the remainder, so **`299 / 100` will always be `2`**. This is one of the few times it should be safe for you to *try it and see*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Buff_Y[2] = (Y / 100) + 0x30;
Buff_Y[1] = (Y / 10) % 10+0x30;
Buff_Y[0] = (Y % 10) + 0x30;
```

This is all good. If you print those three bytes, you will see that they contain the right values.

---

```
SBUF = *Buff_Y;
```

This, however, indicates confusion. `*Buff_Y` is equivalent to `Buff_Y[0]`. That is a single `char` value... If you can only store a single `char` value into `SBUF`, then you can't store the three `char` values you want to store into it.

If we use logic, we can make this inference: That `char` value will be `'0'` if the input you provide is evenly divisible by 10 (that is, when `Y % 10` is `0`)...

While you're thinking about how to change this line of code (and the parts of your code that we can't see), you might also want to think carefully about `while (TI == 0);`. There ought to be a better solution to whatever problem that is attempting to solve.

Answer (score -1):

I'm change this code, can be run, but just received digit in ones.

```
void Data_TX(unsigned char Y)
```

{
    unsigned char Buff_Y[3];

```
Buff_Y[3] = (Y / 100) + 0x30;
Buff_Y[2] = (Y%100)/10+0x30;
Buff_Y[1] = (Y / 10) % 10+0x30;
Buff_Y[0] = (Y % 10) + 0x30;

SBUF = *Buff_Y;
while (TI == 0);
TI = 0;
```

}

```
Data_TX((int)read[2]);
```

Comment: `unsigned char Buff_Y[3];` denotes an array of three (not four) `unsigned char`s. They are `Buff_Y[0]`, `Buff_Y[1]` and `Buff_Y[2]`. `(Y%100)/10+0x30` is functionally identical to `(Y / 10) % 10+0x30`, so the middle character will always be repeated. Stop guessing...

Comment: thanks all, I'm trying to run it. this program could be run. I'm add a loop, problem is solving.

Comment: Do not post answers as updates to a question. SO does not use a forum style thread, but a Q & A style. If you would like to add to your original question, use the edit link under the question and add to the previous content. (People often like to mark such additional sections in their questions with "Update:")